# How to get pdf resource file in wildfly

Tags: resources, wildfly, classpath

I have kept the resource files under the resource folder of the main jar which is a shared module. I am trying to access the file with

`File pdf1File = new File (getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/org/pack/Page2_Template.pdf").getFile());`

I tried `resourceAsStream()` as well.

This is the error:

```
... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\wildfly\content\my-ear.ear\lib\my-jar-6.8.0.0.11-RELEASE-SNAPSHOT.jar\com\org\pack1\Page1_Template.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: Its a pdf template.what to add dynamic content.

Comment: What is the error with `getResourceAsStream()`? It definitely should not be the same error.

Comment: In case of stream null pointer

Comment: Where is the file located in your JAR?

Comment: It's under resources and same structure as Java file

Comment: Try `getResourceAsStream("/com/org/pack/Page2_Template.pdf")` to see if that works. You won't be able to get the file you'll definitely need the stream.